# Python Script to find registry path

Tags: python

Heyy Everybody. I want to know if it's possible to find all registry path of an application. For example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Updates

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office
```

So I want to find all locations that have " `Microsoft\Office`" on on it and display it once.
If is it possible please help me.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) might help.